# Setting up ueye camera for raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to setup an iDs ueye camera on my raspberry pi for a project. I am supposed to run a .gz.run script file that setups everything and then run a daemon that startups the camera.Although on my laptop it works fine (64bit ubuntu) when I setup the 32bit version on the pi and then run the daemon I get the following error:

> /usr/local/share/ueye/ueyeusbd/ueyeusbd: 1:
>   /usr/local/share/ueye/ueyeusbd/ueyeusbd: Syntax error: word unexpected
>   (expecting ")")

I'm suspecting that the camera is not compatible for arm processors , but I would like to find out if there's a way for it to be.

Comment: This question is better for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this saved my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDS has recently released an alpha driver for the Raspberry Pi in the form of an image file. Basically it is a normal Wheezy Rasbian distribution with the ueye-driver (i.e. ueye-daemon) installed. Although the official documentation is sparse (to say the least), everything seems to be in place - the complete Linux SDK should be supported.

You can get the stuff from: http://en.ids-imaging.com/embedded.html

Comment: Thank you very much :) Even after this long your comment helped allot. Cheers